# Adjust line size of a ggplot object

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(iris,aes(Sepal.Width,Petal.Length))+
     geom_line()
p
```

[image]

Imagine that you have a ggplot object and you have no access to the code or data that created this plot. How does one adjust the size/thickness of the plotted line?

I have tried modifying the theme, but that only changes the background lines and not the plotted lines.

```
p+
theme(line=element_line(size=10))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change or add parameters to a specific layer in a ggplot object like this:

```
p$layers[[1]]$aes_params$size = 2
p
```

[image: Line graph with thicker lines]

Answer (score 2):

For more complex ggplots, where you don't know which layers are the `geom_line` layers, you will have to pick out which layers are `geom_line` layers to rewrite their aesthetic parameters:

```r
geomlines <- which(sapply(p$layers, function(x) class(x$geom)[1] == "GeomLine"))

p$layers[geomlines] <- lapply(p$layers[geomlines], function(x) {
  x$aes_params$size <- 2
  x
})

p
```

[image]